# Why is the tkinter after() function not working?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am building a small calculator app. I've decided that for the time being, I want the calculator to display "Syntax Error" (if there is one) for 1.5 seconds before clearing the input field (where the numbers are displayed). The problem is that the program won't clear the entry when I declare `input_field.after(1500, clear)`. Here is my `clear()` method (which is working everywhere else). It also updates a boolean but it's irrelevant, so it basically does one thing for the sake of this question.

```
def clear():
    input_field.delete(0, END)
```

If my function works, why is the "Syntax Error" text not getting cleared after 1.5 seconds?

EDIT: this is my equals() method:

```
def equals():
    syntax_error = False
    input_field['state'] = 'normal'
    global ans, last_key_equals
    expression = input_field.get().replace("x", "*").replace("ans", str(ans))
    if len(expression) == 0:
        return
    try:
        result = simple_eval(expression)
    except SyntaxError:
        syntax_error = True
        result = "0"
        clear()
        input_field.insert(0, "Syntax Error")
        input_field.after(1500, clear)

    if not syntax_error:
        clear()
        input_field.insert(0, result)
        ans = int(result)
    last_key_equals = True
    input_field['state'] = 'readonly'
```

Comment: Better provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It is because you have changed the entry to *readonly* state before the `clear()` function is executed by `.after()`.

Comment: I see the difference, but where exactly did I change it to readonly before the `clear()` function? I specifically put `input_field['state'] = 'normal'` at the start of the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable writing to the input field.  Change your clear function to:

```
def clear():
    prev_state = input_field['state']
    input_field['state'] = 'normal'
    input_field.delete(0, END)
    input_field['state'] = prev_state
```

Comment: Just to expand on that: You can't change the contents of a `<tkinter.Entry>` object unless the state is `"normal"`.

Comment: First of all, since I do `input_field.insert(...)` after the clear method, I can't have it making the state readonly again.
Also, now after I have a syntax error the input field is normal but keeps being that way until a button press despite me changing it at the end of `equals()`.

Comment: The clear method I wrote here just resets the input field state to writeable, clears the field, then returns the input field state to whatever it was prior to the call.

Comment: I ended up creating a new insert function which also starts and ends with changing the states and it all works now. Cheers.